# Can I prevent forever from restarting my node script in certain cases?

Tags: node.js, forever

I have a node script which I run from the command line with forever: `forever index.js`

When that script crashes, I want forever to restart it, but not all the time. There are certain cases which I know will need human intervention to fix. In those cases, I hoped it would be possible to exit the process in a way forever wouldn't restart it.

Is there any way to do this?

I originally thought I could have the process restarted with `process.exit(1)` and not restarted with `process.exit(0)`, but apparently this is not the case.

Here is another way to put it:

- Fill in the blanks in the code below.
- Save the result as *index.js*
- Launch the script with `forever index.js`
- The script should print "hello", exit, and not be restarted

  ```
  setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("hello")
     // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
  }, 1500)
  ```

By the way, the delay in there is just work around the default --minUpTime of 1 second

Answer (score 2):

*forever* supports exit signal customization with the --killSignal option:

```
--killSignal     Support exit signal customization (default is SIGKILL),
                 used for restarting script gracefully e.g. --killSignal=SIGTERM
```

The above is for instructing forever with which kill signal to stop the script forever has started. To selectively stop forever from running a script based on the way the script has exited, you'll need to use [forever-monitor](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever-monitor).

First, your script will need to send a specific signal when you want forever to *not* restart it. Here's our script.js:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('hello');

    //process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGKILL'); // this will cause forever to restart the script.

    setTimeout(function () {
        process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM');  // this will cause forever to stop the script.
    }, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

Then, we need an additional script with forever-monitor (let's call it *script-monitor.js*):

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('script.js', {
    max: 10,
    silent: false,
    args: []
});

child.on('restart', function() {
    console.error('Forever restarting script for ' + child.times + ' time');
});

child.on('exit:code', function(code) {
    console.error('Forever detected script exited with code ' + code);
    if (143 === code) child.stop(); // don't restart the script on SIGTERM
});

child.start();
```

Now you can run script.js by running: `node script-monitor.js`

For convenience, [here is a list](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) of signal events in node.js.

Comment: I've read this but I don't know how to use it. When I `process.exit()`, I can pass in an integer. I can't pass in SIGTERM or SIGKILL. Also, what does killSignal actually do? If I set it to SIGTERM, what default behaviour will stop happening? What new behaviour appears?

Comment: I guess the best solution depends on when you don't want forever to restart the process. For example, if you only want forever to restart the script when you deliberately `process.exit()` in your script, then you could specify `--killSignal=SIGTERM` If you needed more customized situations, then you may want to consider looking into forever-monitor and writing a node script with forever-monitor that implements in what cases to restart/not restart and then runs your node script.

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clearer. I've tried using `--killSignal=SIGTERM` and the `process.exit()`, but the script is still restarted by forever...

Comment: Hi @Shawn. It appears i've got --killSignal backwards. You can use --killSignal to tell forever which signal to pass to the script before forever stops it. I've revised my answer with a solution to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Marco's answer, but signalling is not required.  It can be replaced with an exit code of your choice (say 0).  The code then looks like this:

`script.js`:

```
function myStopCondition() {
  console.log('leaving');
  exit(0);
}

console.log('hello');
setTimeout(myStopCondition, 2000);
```

`almost_forever.js`:

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

var child = new (forever.Monitor)('script.js', {
  max: 10,
  silent: false,
  args: [] 
});

child.on('restart', function() {
  console.error('Forever restarting script for ' + child.times + ' time');
});

child.on('exit:code', function(code) {
  console.error('Forever detected script exited with code ' + code);
  if (0 === code) child.stop(); // don't restart the script on exit(1)
});

child.start();
```

Then `npm i forever-monitor [--save]` and run as

```
node almost_forever.js
```